# Gutenberg block Social links problem with render

Tags: php, reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-gutenberg

When I add block Social links in the template part and after that choose this template part with block Template part - nothing is rendering. Why it's happening? Maybe attributes don't pass trough blocks in this case? but it looks like a bug in the core.

```
<!-- wp:social-links -->
<ul class="wp-block-social-links">
    <!-- wp:social-link /-->
</ul>
<!-- /wp:social-links -->
```

Or when I create a template part like this - is any possible way to pass dynamically attributes from the editor to template part instead hardcoded url?

```
<!-- wp:social-links -->
<ul class="wp-block-social-links">
    <!-- wp:social-link {"url":"https://wordpress.org/patterns/","service":"instagram"} /-->
    <!-- wp:social-link {"url":"https://wordpress.org/patterns/","service":"bandcamp"} /-->
   <!-- wp:social-link {"url":"https://wordpress.org/patterns/","service":"twitter"} /-->
   <!-- wp:social-link {"url":"https://wordpress.org/patterns/","service":"twitch"} /-->
```

I try to add block Social Links in the template part and need to have the opportunity to choose template part with social links with block Template Part. And seeing results on the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

When the Social Links block is inserted into the template part, a valid link for each social you add, eg "Instagram", "Bandcamp", etc... is required otherwise it will not render a link on the frontend - producing the markup posted in your question.

To insert the Social Links block into multiple template parts without having to set the URLs each time, convert your configured Social Links block to a [Reusable Block](https://wordpress.com/support/wordpress-editor/blocks/reusable-block/). By using a Reusable Block in your templates, you will also be able to easily update/add/remove your social links site-wide in the future if needed.

[image: Social Links as Resuable Block in Template (Header)]